# list video devices via terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

How do you list a computer's video devices via terminal? Is there a command that lists them?

Comment: With "video devices" to exactly what kind of devices are you referring? May be more clean way that system_profiler

Answer (score 13):

To list video **output** devices (e.g. monitors),

```
$ system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

This produces output that looks like this:

```
Graphics/Displays:

    Intel HD Graphics 4000:

      Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 4000
      Type: GPU
      Bus: Built-In
      VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
      Vendor: Intel
      Device ID: 0x0166
      Revision ID: 0x0009
      Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v4
      Displays:
        Color LCD:
          Display Type: LCD
          Resolution: 1440 x 900 (Widescreen eXtended Graphics Array Plus)
          UI Looks like: 1440 x 900
          Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
          Connection Type: Internal
```

To list video **input** devices (e.g. webcams),

```
$ system_profiler SPCameraDataType
```

This produces output that looks like this:

```
Camera:

    FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):

      Model ID: UVC Camera VendorID_1452 ProductID_34064
      Unique ID: 0x1a11000005ca8510
```

To get just the device names, filter the list accordingly:

```
$ system_profiler SPCameraDataType | grep "^    [^ ]" | sed "s/    //" | sed "s/://"
```

This produces output that looks like this:

```
FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):
```

Comment: This really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`system_profiler`

Comment: man page here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html

Answer (score 1):

```
system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

or

```
ioreg | grep -i display
```

Note that the system_profiler command is case sensitive.